# HashMap + Lambda. How to add a new value <List> if is null

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to "translate" this code to use it with Java 8 new features. Lambda, map.compute.

But there is an error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ArrayList<DayDetailsBean>
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: you are calling the add which returns a boolean, when it is expecting an `ArrayList`. I would try doing `(v == null) ? new ArrayList<DayDetailsBean>() : v` and then after this calling `forEach`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). Which:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.
>
> returns the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null

```
map.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<DayDetailsBean>()).add(dayDetails);
```

Comment: But I need to add a new element to the value<List> if the key is present.

Comment: @Deam yes, If the key is present, it will just return the value that it was mapped to